# How to simplify this expression further to find derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I simplify this expression?

$(1+D_1.c_1+D_2c_2)(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}$ - $(1+D_2c_2)(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}$

$D1$ and $D2$ are two variables. $a$ is negative while b is positive and less than 1. I want to see when this term is decreasing/increasing in $D_2$.

Comment: So, you just want the derivative with respect to $D_2$, and everything else is treated as a constant? How much do you know of derivative rules? I would just do it by brute force.

Comment: Yeah I just want derivative with respect to $D_2$. I have a good grasp of derivative rules. So is there anyway I can use binomial theorem to cancel out the similar terms?

Comment: There probably is, but I don't really think that is easier, honestly. I'll post the derivative for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is rarely more convenient to simply expressions before taking derivatives unless the simplification is *very* major.

Let $F(D_2)=(1+D_1.c_1+D_2c_2)(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}-(1+D_2c_2)(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}$. Then, using the product, power, and sum rules, we have:

$$\frac{dF}{dD_2}=(1+D_1.c_1+D_2c_2)\frac{d}{dD_2}(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}+(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{d}{dD_2}(1+D_1.c_1+D_2c_2)-(1+D_2c_2)\frac{d}{dD_2}(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}-(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{d}{dD_2}(1+D_2c_2)$$

Taking the indicated derivatives (utilizing chain rule along the way) gives:

$$\frac{dF}{dD_2}=(1+D_1.c_1+D_2c_2){\frac{b}{a}}(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}-1}(p_2^a)+(D_1.p_1^a+D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}(c_2)-(1+D_2c_2){\frac{b}{a}}(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}-1}(p_2^a)-(D_2p_2^a)^{\frac{b}{a}}(c_2)$$

In the above steps I have not altered the order in which anything appears, so that it should be easy to follow. In my humble opinion, it is best to make all variables and constants represented by their own single letter or something. I don't know your application, but if $D_2$ is the second density functional or something, I would just replace it with a $D$ in your scratch work when you do the derivatives. Avoids mistakes. Anyway, unless I have missed something in the dense notation, that is probably the nicest form you'll get.

Comment: Thanks for this! I also got this expression, but it's very hard to find the conditions for b and a such that the derivative wrt $D_2$ will be greater than 0, so I was looking to see if I can cancel out some terms by using the binomial theorem. All the coefficients c and p are positive, $D_1$ is also positive but a is negative. Do you think this is possible? Would it be nicer if I do cancel out the similar terms? I tried applying binomial theorem but it was messy so I didn't even get to the final result.

Comment: If it *is* possible, it will take for more time than just writing it out, I fear. By the way, if you find an answer useful, consider upvoting or accepting it!